# Is it possible to find cell phone users on a wifi network

Tags: android, ios, wifi

I have never made a cell phone app before so forgive the awkward question.

My idea involves starting a chat room within a Wifi network. Is it possible to make an app where one user starts a chat room and then only people on the same Wifi network could see it and join?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a really interesting tutorial that explains how to connect to other devices over Wi-Fi or Bluetooth.  It even has a cool little demo project where you can create a chat room.

[Understanding Multipeer Connectivity Framework in iOS 7 – Part 1](http://www.appcoda.com/intro-multipeer-connectivity-framework-ios-programming/)